# Making a question

Tags: grammar

I am confused and want to know which is the correct sentence?

- Why is the Security Setting missing in CP?
- Why the Security Setting is missing in CP?
- Why the Security Setting missing in CP?

Comment: Why is the Security Setting missing in CP?

Comment: Could you please, add your comment as an answer to accept it. also Please add some clarification or a simple link that guide me to can  make  questions easily :) thanks

Comment: Learn thoroughly, do exercises, you will be a good questioner. Here is the link: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/verbs-questions-and-negatives